# How to copy one form elements into another through jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to copy one form elements into another

```
<a href="#" onClick="copySelectedOptions(document.forms[0]['lstusr'],document.forms[0]['lstto'],false);return false;">
```

It is already written in PHP. I want it in JSP.

Comment: Please elaborate. Where do you have servlet here? You will have to do the copying manually, one request parameter at a time.

Comment: Can someone edit tags for this question?

Answer (score 2):

Your example means that you wish to copy form elements on **client** side. In this case the question about PHP or JSP is irrelevant: they both are server side technologies. So, just find the function `copySelectedOptions` implemented in javascript you used before (probably with PHP on server side that does not matter), include it into your HTML using `<script>` tag and use it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't see how this becomes a Java / JSP / Servlet question. The `copySelectedOptions` function is a JavaScript function and can be easily reproduced by copying and pasting into your JSP file.